# Why wont the label text update?

Tags: vb.net

For some reason, the label text refuses to update until the ComputerTurn() sub. Does anyone know why it would be doing that?

```
Sub PlayerTurn(ByVal no As Integer)
    pile -= no
    lblDisplay.Text = "There are " + pile.ToString + " Stones in the Pile"
    If pile = 0 Then
        EndGame("Computer")
    End If
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    ComputerTurn()
End Sub

Sub ComputerTurn()
    Dim stones As Integer = 0
    Do
        stones = RndInt(1, 3)
    Loop While Not CheckNo(stones)
    pile -= stones
    lblCompDisplay.Text = "Computer took " + pile.ToString + " Stones"
    If pile = 0 Then
        EndGame("Player")
    Else
        btnGo.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are instructing the UI thread to sleep.  If the UI thread is asleep, the UI is not going to get updated.  Take it as a rule that you NEVER sleep the UI thread.  If you want to pause for two seconds before doing something then use a `Timer` with an `Interval` of 2000.